# Is there Task Completion info on GitHub Issues API?

Tags: github, markdown, github-api, github-flavored-markdown

On GitHub Flavored Markdown you can write something like:

```
- [ ] Subtask 1
- [ ] Subtask 2
- [x] Subtask 3
```

This will render as a list of three checkboxes, the last one checked. That also gives a nice bonus to Issues listing as it includes a progress bar for the given issue:

[image: Three issues with progress bar]

Is this present in the GitHub API? If not, how could we achieve that? Only by manually parsing the Issue body? Finally, is there a specific place for requesting API features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this present in the GitHub API?

No. The GitHub API does not currently expose task completion progress.

> If not, how could we achieve that? Only by manually parsing the Issue body?

That is probably your best bet at the moment.

> Finally, is there a specific place for requesting API features?

Indeed! Get in touch at [https://github.com/contact](https://github.com/contact?form%5Bsubject%5D=API+v3). GitHub welcomes feature requests, and it's especially helpful if you can explain how a particular feature would benefit you (e.g., a description of the workflows that a particular API enhancement would enable).

Comment: thanks man. I've suggested HuBoard owner to talk directly to them, as I think he'll get more attention :)
https://github.com/rauhryan/huboard/issues/529

Comment: I have the same question. I'm working on workflow automation, and I want to be able to enumerate the tasks in an issue's tasklist. Still no specific REST API support?